# How to check if an item is in a list.txt in PHP?

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

I need a function like in python is:

```
if i in list.txt:
    print ("i");
else:
    print ("i is not in list.txt")
```

But i want a thing like this in php.
If someone could help me I would appreciate it.Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: PHP doesn't have lists. Arrays in PHP are hashmaps. A classical (linked) list would have sequential access only (eg. searching = iterating from the begin until the item is found.. worst case: all items searched, but no match). With hashmaps it is much easier...

Comment: I don't know python can you define what you are trying to match? Lines, words, etc. Also what is the size of the file and what are your memory constraints? Possibly `file()` and `in_array` could be used

Comment: What is a `list.txt`? Do you mean a plain text file?

Comment: yes,a plain text file.

Comment: Elaborating on user3783243's comment, a one-liner would be something like: `if (in_array($i, file('list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES), true) ) {...} else {...}`. This code, however, loads the entire file in memory so it's suboptimal for large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents` to read file contents and then `strpos` to search for the word in read data.

```
    $fileContents = file_get_contents("list.txt");
    if(strpos($fileContents, $word) !== false)
        echo "i";
    else
        echo "i is not in list.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [SplFileObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) class that returning pointing

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject("list.txt");

while (!$file->eof()) {
    $line = $file->fgets();
    if (strpos($line, $word) !== false)
      echo $line; // Print content 
}
```